# Apache Spark Read Json Stream Returns Null Only

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, inputstream

Hi I am new to spark & scala. I have started write application which will read json file & print the strema in console. But It always print values as Null.

This is the program I have tried.

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[3]")
      .appName("Demo")
      .getOrCreate()

    val userSchema = new StructType()
      .add("name", "string")
      .add("age", "integer")


    val df = spark.readStream
      .schema(userSchema)
      .json("/home/sajith/Desktop/temp_data/demo/cpy/")

    df.printSchema()

    df.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

And This is the sample Json file

```
{
 "name":"Sajith", 
 "age": 55
}
```

When I put json file to directory It gives this result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reason was the json data need to be single line.

```
{"name":"Sajith","age":55}
```

Comment: (https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-and-write-json-file/) please, see

Comment: What if I have multiple json

Comment: @TejasPatel Haven't tested that